# Сортировка выборки из сложного словаря по значению

Tags: python, python-3.x

Нужно из словаря вида:

```
dict = {
'KEY_01': {2010: [X, Y], 2011: [X, Y], 2012: [X, Y], 2013: [X, Y]},
'KEY_0X': {2010: [X, Y], 2011: [X, Y], 2012: [X, Y], 2013: [X, Y]}
}
```

организовать вывод данных, за выбранный год, сортированный по значению **Х**:

```
2010 # (или любой другой выбранный год)
KEY_0c   X   Y
KEY_0a   X   Y
 . . . 
KEY_0b   X   Y
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот так вы можете взять данные за 2010 год:

```
[ x['2010'] for x in dict.values() ]
```

А вот так вы можете его отсортировать:

```
sorted( [x['2010'] for x in dict.values() ], key = lambda x: x[0] )
```

**Обновление 1.**

Без потери ключа:

```
[ [k] + x['2010'] for (k,x) in dict.items() ]
```

Сортировка:

```
sorted( [ [k] + x['2010'] for (k,x) in dict.items() ], key = lambda x: x[1])
```

Comment: Спасибо. Это почти работает. Дело в том, что я так теряю привязку данных [year: [X, Y]] к ключам KEY_0X. Я невнятно описал проблему, прошу прощения. Мне нужен вот такой вывод:
`2010 # (или любой другой выбранный год) KEY_00 - X - Y KEY_01 - X - Y . . . KEY_0N - X - Y` отсортированный по Х

Comment: @Alexey: Смотрите обновление (если правильно понял вашу задачу)

Comment: Большое спасибо! Теперь все работает! )

Comment: @Alexey: На здоровье! Очень был рад вам помочь!

Comment: @Alexey Внесите, пожалуйста, обновление в формулировку вопроса, чтобы другим участникам с такой же проблемой было проще его найти